# Как отправить через nginx, параметр в python скрипт, и получить ответом ссылку?

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, uwsgi

У меня есть скрипт на python который генерирует определенные ссылки к другому ресурсу, мне нужно настроить nginx, так чтобы пользователь заходя по ссылке вида example.com/ip=1.1.1.1, попадал на ресурс, по ссылке которую сгенерировал python скрипт, и соотвественно нужен проброс параметра ip=1.1.1.1 в python скрипт.

Подскажите самый простой способ это сделать, если можно с примером. Спасибо!